# Contact form 7 [_url] issue

Tags: php, wordpress, utf-8, hebrew, contact-form-7

The URL addresses on my website are with Hebrew chars.
I'm using the [url_] special mail tag feature and I'm getting encoded urls address on the mail message.

The problem - i got the next question marks, and not the hebrew. I guess its not caused from DB because its mail-sender plugin... so what cause it?

example:

> http://www.site-name.co.il/������/

PHP site, windows server.
Wordpress, using Contact form 7 plugin.

my wp-config db line:

```
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci');
```

Asked on plugin developers forum by someone else before 6 months, without answer.

How i can get the hebrew chars and not question marks?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How i can get the hebrew chars and not question marks :)

Comment: Srry, I'm not able to test this. :) I've added tags `utf-8` and `hebrew`. Maybe this would attract someone who can help...

Comment: @hek2mgl it did attract. Anyway, I'm unable to reproduce the problem, I don't understand you. Maybe you can link to your site (if there's a live one) or to the WP forum you mentioned.

Comment: @NadavS. I'm not the OP :)

Comment: @hek2mgl, I know. It wasn't clear but I talked to Bside.

Comment: OK.. You should address him using `@Bside` so that he will get noticed...

Answer (score 0):

Try to Add this to `.htaccess` file or create it and put into domain folder.

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8  
AddCharset utf-8 *  
  <IfModule mod_charset.c>  
    CharsetSourceEnc utf-8  
    CharsetDefault utf-8  
  </IfModule>
```

But I advice use `[_post_title]`.
Note that the `[_post_*]` tag has value only when you put the contact form into content of a post or a page. They are not available if the contact form is put inside a sidebar widget. (inside loop)